Intermittent null return in Mockito unit tests for Spring service methods
I am encountering an intermittent issue with my unit tests for a Spring service where the method under test occasionally returns null. This issue is random and affects different methods during the act phase of the tests.
package fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.services;

import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.Exception.CoachNotFoundException;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.assemblers.ModelAssembler;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.dto.CoachDto;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.mappers.CoachMapper;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.models.Coach;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.repositories.CoachRepository;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.ressources.CoachModel;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.hateoas.PagedModel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class CoachServiceImpl implements CoachService {
    private final CoachRepository coachRepository;
    private final ModelAssembler<CoachDto, CoachModel> coachModelAssembler;
    private final ModelAssembler<Page<CoachModel>, PagedModel<CoachModel>> coachPagedModelAssembler;
    private final CoachMapper coachMapper;
    private final SortUtil sortUtil;

    public CoachServiceImpl(CoachRepository coachRepository, ModelAssembler<CoachDto, CoachModel> coachModelAssembler, ModelAssembler<Page<CoachModel>, PagedModel<CoachModel>> coachPagedModelAssembler, CoachMapper coachMapper, SortUtil sortUtil) {
        this.coachRepository = coachRepository;
        this.coachModelAssembler = coachModelAssembler;
        this.coachPagedModelAssembler = coachPagedModelAssembler;
        this.coachMapper = coachMapper;
        this.sortUtil = sortUtil;
    }

    @Override
    public CoachModel createCoach(CoachDto coachDto) {
        Coach savedCoach = coachRepository.save(Coach.builder()
                .email(coachDto.email())
                .name(coachDto.name())
                .phone(coachDto.phone())
                .surname(coachDto.surname())
                .build());
        return coachModelAssembler.toModel(coachMapper.toDto(savedCoach));
    }

    @Override
    public PagedModel<CoachModel> getAllCoaches(int page, int size, List<String> sort) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, this.sortUtil.createSort(sort));
        return coachPagedModelAssembler.toModel(coachRepository.findAll(pageable).map(coachMapper::toDto).map(coachModelAssembler::toModel));
    }

    @Override
    public CoachModel getCoachById(Long id) throws CoachNotFoundException {
        return coachRepository.findById(id)
                .map(coachMapper::toDto)
                .map(coachModelAssembler::toModel)
                .orElseThrow(CoachNotFoundException::new);
    }

    @Override
    public CoachModel updateCoach(Long id, CoachDto coachDto) throws CoachNotFoundException {
        Coach coachToUpdate = coachRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(CoachNotFoundException::new);
        coachToUpdate.setEmail(coachDto.email());
        coachToUpdate.setName(coachDto.name());
        coachToUpdate.setPhone(coachDto.phone());
        coachToUpdate.setSurname(coachDto.surname());
        Coach savedCoach = coachRepository.save(coachToUpdate);
        return coachModelAssembler.toModel(coachMapper.toDto(savedCoach));
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCoach(Long id) {
        coachRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}

package fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.services;

import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.Exception.CoachNotFoundException;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.assemblers.ModelAssembler;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.dto.CoachDto;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.mappers.CoachMapper;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.models.Coach;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.repositories.CoachRepository;
import fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.ressources.CoachModel;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.data.domain.*;
import org.springframework.hateoas.PagedModel;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.reset;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CoachServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private CoachRepository coachRepository;

    @Mock
    private ModelAssembler<CoachDto, CoachModel> coachModelAssembler;

    @Mock
    private ModelAssembler<Page<CoachModel>, PagedModel<CoachModel>> coachPagedModelAssembler;

    @Mock
    private CoachMapper coachMapper;

    @Mock
    private SortUtil sortUtil;

    @InjectMocks
    private CoachServiceImpl coachService;

    @Test
    public void testGetCoachById() throws CoachNotFoundException {
        // Arrange
        Coach coach = Coach.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .name("John")
                .surname("Doe")
                .email("john.doe@example.com")
                .phone("1234567890")
                .build();
        CoachDto coachDto = new CoachDto(1L, "John", "Doe", "john.doe@example.com", "1234567890");
        CoachModel coachModel = new CoachModel(coachDto);

        given(coachRepository.findById(1L)).willReturn(Optional.of(coach));
        given(coachMapper.toDto(coach)).willReturn(coachDto);
        given(coachModelAssembler.toModel(coachDto)).willReturn(coachModel);

        // Act
        CoachModel result = coachService.getCoachById(1L);

        // Debugging logs
        System.out.println("Fetched Coach ID: " + Objects.requireNonNull(result.getContent()).id());

        // Assert
        assertThat(result).isNotNull();
        assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(result.getContent()).id()).isEqualTo(1L);
        then(coachRepository).should(times(1)).findById(1L);
    }


}

I have tried to isolate the problem by resetting mocks, verifying mock configurations, and ensuring proper test isolation, but the issue persists. Above is the code for my service implementation (CoachServiceImpl) and the unit test class (CoachServiceTest).
I have added logs and ensured the mocks are reset before and after each test. Despite this, the issue of intermittent null values persists.
Has anyone have a solution or suggestions on how to further debug and resolve this problem?
EDIT :
I have reduced the tests to only the testGetCoachById() method. The
issue occurs at this line:
CoachModel result = coachService.getCoachById(1L);

Sometimes, result is null, and sometimes it returns the correct value.
My stack trace when error :
fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.Exception.CoachNotFoundException
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403)
at fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.services.CoachServiceImpl.getCoachById(CoachServiceImpl.java:51)
at fr.hoenheimsports.trainingservice.services.CoachServiceTest.testGetCoachById(CoachServiceTest.java:147)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:728)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:218)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:139)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:119)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:89)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)


Add  error you getting to your question.

Too much code. Reduce to a single method to showcase the problem (see [mre]). Include the exact error message, line with error, and stack trace.

I corrected my message

I faced an issue where your tests for the CoachServiceImpl class were sometimes failing randomly. This problem occurred because Mockito was incorrectly mocking the coachModelAssembler and coachPagedModelAssembler dependencies, occasionally swapping them.
The root of the issue was due to the usage of generic interfaces ModelAssembler for both coachModelAssembler and coachPagedModelAssembler. Mockito had difficulty differentiating between these two mocks when they were injected into CoachServiceImpl, causing unpredictable behavior during the tests.
The solution involves modifying the code to use concrete classes instead of generic interfaces for the dependencies. By using the specific implementations (CoachModelAssemblerImpl and CoachPagedModelAssemblerImpl), you eliminate the ambiguity for Mockito, ensuring that it correctly injects the proper mocks.
I don't know if this is a coding error on my part or if Mockito should handle this problem better.
The best solution still seems to stay on interfaces:
public interface CoachModelAssembler extends ModelAssembler<CoachDto, CoachModel> {
}

@Component("coachModelAssembler")
public class CoachModelAssemblerImpl implements CoachModelAssembler {
    // Implementation...
}

public interface CoachPagedModelAssembler extends ModelAssembler<Page<CoachModel>, PagedModel<CoachModel>> {
}

@Component("coachPagedModelAssembler")
public class CoachPagedModelAssemblerImpl implements CoachPagedModelAssembler {
    // Implementation...
}

